# Proposing firebase-functions tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-disambiguation

Maybe it's a bit too soon, but I think it's going to be very useful as Google-cloud-functions and Firebase-functions require different specific knowledge.

As I don't have the required reputation points (maybe never), I'm suggesting it already.

Comment: Are there questions currently on the site that this tag could be applied?  If not, then this tag is definitely pre-mature.  Tags cannot exist with a question to apply the tag too.

Comment: I can mention a couple already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865803/use-other-references-value-from-firebase-realtime-trigger-functions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616809/sending-automated-emails-from-firebase-through-google-cloud-platform-no-third-p

Comment: Searchign for "firebase functions" questions there are already a couple hundred from where most do talk only from firebase-functions specifically, and not google-cloud-functions (which is being used as the tag for them already, but is not the real case).

Comment: I see in one of the examples you mentioned, you suggested google-cloud-functions as a tag via edit.  Are the tags related enough that they mean the same thing?  Or are they separate products?  Or is one the older name?

Comment: Both products have the same (public Beta) age... 1 week, nevertheless in the case of Firebase Functions it was a very expected functionality since 2014 (they even showed it as triggers on a conference). In the case of Google-Cloud-Functions it automates APIs from GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and in Firebase it works with many specific functionalities mainly in Node.js which are exclusive from Firebase, so yes.. separate products... Maybe you are not the one who should answer this, I would expect someone like @frank-van-puffelen to answer

Comment: I doubt a user with virtually zero meta contributions will user pop in and provide feedback.  While your questions seems to lack details about why the tag is necessary,from your comments combined with the precedents of the existing firebase-* tags, it seems like the tag might have some value, so i will add it to one of your example questions - feel free to add it where you think it is needed.

Comment: There, the tag exists - please consider providing a suggested edit to the [tag wiki and the except](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/) to help provide some guidance for the tag

Comment: An extraction from the [original description](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) might be correct:
"Functions you write that respond to events generated by Triggers from Firebase features like Realtime Database, Firebase Authentication, Firebase Analytics, Storage, Pub/Sub or even HTTP Triggers"
I hope they don't have different plans for this inside Google.

Comment: I believe you should include "Cloud Functions for Firebase" in the description as clearly deferred by Frank here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854865/what-is-the-difference-between-cloud-function-and-firebase-functions/42859932#42859932

Comment: You can propose your own edits to the tag wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/125361

Comment: *firebaser here* Google Cloud Functions is an infrastructure to run "serverless" functions on Google infrastructure. Firebase has integrated with GCF in what is called Cloud Functions for Firebase. There is no separate product called Firebase Functions, just a NPM module (about which few questions have occurred). So I've been retagging questions with [google-cloud-functions] and [firebase] (where relevant). See my answer here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854865/what-is-the-difference-between-cloud-function-and-firebase-functions/42859932#42859932